# use socat as a service 24/7

Tags: networking, iptables, socat

We have a server which main focus is to stream data from one point to another.
e.g.

```
transfer data form 192.168.0.10:5000 to 192.168.0.20:6000
transfer data form 232.0.0.1:5000 to 192.168.0.20:6000
transfer data form 192.168.0.255:5000 to 192.168.0.20:6000
```

I assume the best way to do that would by `iptables` but since we need to support multicast this doesn't seem to be an option (at least for multicast)

I know how I can make socat run as a service but my question is *if* I should run socat as a service.
Sometimes there might be hours where it would idle and days where it would transfer data every second.

*Is socat ready to run 24/7 and receiving/transmitting data?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We did some test streaming videos via socat for a day or two and so far performance and system impact seems good.
First feedback from customers also.

You have to make sure that you don't use socats `fork` and don't log extensively because that will have noticeable negative impact on your system.

I suggest to use socats `UDP-RECV` for incoming traffic and `UDP-DATAGRAM` for outgoing traffic.
This combination proved to be the must performant and stable solution.
Other wouldn't work are have a negative impact on the system.
Be sure to read socats documentation it will explain how the different options work.